# write a text file with a list of matrices in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to pull together a bunch of matrices (different dimensions) into a list and then write that list to a text file, with line breaks in between each matrix. Here's a dummy example:

```
x <- matrix(0, nrow=2, ncol=7)
y <- matrix(0, nrow=7, ncol=7)
z <- matrix(0, nrow=4, ncol=7)
n_y <- t(matrix(nrow(allpar12), nrow(allpar12))) #just need a 1x2 matrix with the nrow(x) in each cell, this probably isn't the best way to do it.
test <- list(x, y, y, n_y, z)

lapply(test, cat, "\n", file="test.txt", append=T)
```

The text file looks like this:
[image: output]

It seems that the matrices are being printed as vectors. How can I change the code so they print as matrices?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for the `write.list` function from the `erer` package https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/erer/versions/2.5/topics/write.list

Comment: How do you want your output to look?  If all matrices are of the same number of columns, I'd stack these together, convert it to a data frame and use tools like `write.table` to save a csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
create_text <- function(m){
  res <- ""
  m <- formatC(m, width = max(nchar(trunc(m))), flag = "", format = "d")
  for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
     res <- paste0(res, paste0(paste(as.character(m[i, 1:ncol(m)]), collapse = "\t"), "\n"))
  }
  return(res)
}

text <- lapply(test, create_text)

writeLines(unlist(text), "listmat.txt")
```

Comment: This generates exactly what I was shooting for, thanks @jimbalan !

Comment: How could I adjust this function if one of the matrices has character values instead of numeric values?